# How to calculate increases in equity of a valuing asset

Tags: finance, portfolio-management

I would like to know how to calculate equity of an owned asset.
My problem specifically is that I own a BTC wallet and have some family members contributing to that wallet as well.
Having person A B and C invested.
Lets say on the day of creation 10000 euros were added to the wallet.

5000 from person A - 50% of the wallet.

2000 from person B - 20% of the wallet.

3000 from person C - 30% of the wallet.

This math is pretty straight forward and easy to do, the problem comes from adding later on to this wallet.

Lets say over time the wallet values and is now worth 20000, meaning everyone doubled their initial investment.

But at 20000 person A decides to add 2000 more to the wallet.
How would one calculate how much equity in the wallet that person is supposed to add?
The wallet would now be worth 22000 and 2000 of that is 10%, should person A get 60% of the wallet now and person B and C lose 5%? should person C lose more given that he has more % of the wallet?

How would one go about calculating this to make sure value equity is intact?

Thank you for your time and I hope I was explicit enough in the question.

Comment: I’d argue that you need to keep track of the performance of each individual contribution.

Comment: There are established methods to track an Investment Partnership or a Mutual Fund. When the partnership is established an (arbitrary) number of shares is created and they are given a per/share value or "NAV/sh". Each partner receives some shares. Therafter when someone invests additional money they are given additional shares, based on an updated NAV/sh based on the current value of the portfolio. When someone takes money out they give back ("redeem") some shares to the fund at a fair NAV/sh. So you need to keep track of 2 things: how many shares each person holds and the current NAV/sh